# How to check whether variable was assigned if NullReferenceException occurs after null check in Razor code of View

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, nullreferenceexception

> I am trying to change content of div element whenever checkbox is checked by appending some text which I got from Linq, but I get NullReference exception while assigning list to m. Code is below. What is wrong?

```
 onchange = "if(this.checked){
 @ {
   string s = "h";
   string w = "";

   var r = from c in Model.Roles.Keys
   from a in Model.AllRoles
   where a.Name == c select a;
   List < AspNetRoles > m = new List < AspNetRoles > ();
   if (r != null) { **
     m = r.ToList();
   } **
   if (r.Count() != 0) {

     foreach(AspNetRoles role in r) {
       foreach(AspNetUsers user in role.AspNetUsers) {
         Model.Hashset.Add(user);
       }
     }
     foreach(AspNetUsers us in Model.Hashset) {
       s += us.UserName + ',';
     }
     w = s;
   }
 }

 $('#users').append('@w');
 }
```

Comment: what is onchange  in this context suppose to be?  The way it is written, it is going to execute immediately, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: it would be great to have this function work only for user interactions and not in the stage of generating this page(I mean filling this checkbox with default value),but it is the only way that I know.